# php command not found after yum install php55-php-cli

Tags: php, centos, yum

So I am using the EPEL repo with yum, When I run the command everything installs fine:

```
sudo yum install php55-php-cli
```

However when I run:

```
php
```

I get the error:

```
php command not found
```

Does anyone know why ?

**update**

People are throwing around different packages to install which is wrong, when I do `yum search php5 | grep 'cli'` the results are:

```
php54-php-cli.x86_64 : Command-line interface for PHP
php54-php-pecl-ircclient.x86_64 : IRC Client
php54-php-pecl-radius.x86_64 : Radius client library
php54-php-pecl-stomp.x86_64 : Stomp client extension
php54-php-pecl-yaz.x86_64 : Z39.50/SRU client
php55-php-cli.x86_64 : Command-line interface for PHP
php55-php-pecl-ircclient.x86_64 : IRC Client
php55-php-pecl-radius.x86_64 : Radius client library
php55-php-pecl-stomp.x86_64 : Stomp client extension
php55-php-pecl-yaz.x86_64 : Z39.50/SRU client
php56-php-cli.x86_64 : Command-line interface for PHP
php56-php-pecl-ircclient.x86_64 : IRC Client
php56-php-pecl-radius.x86_64 : Radius client library
php56-php-pecl-stomp.x86_64 : Stomp client extension
php56-php-pecl-yaz.x86_64 : Z39.50/SRU client
```

Comment: Try  `echo '<?php echo "test\n"; ?>' > test.php` and then `php -q test.php`. When `test` shows in your console, it works. If not, there went - most likely - something wrong with the installation.

Comment: the php command is not found, is it something to do with where yum installing php55-php-cli ?

Comment: By the way, try `sudo yum install php55-cli` or `sudo yum install php5-cli`. php55-php-cli doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: try if command `/usr/local/php/bin/php` works

Comment: I did exactly - php55-php-cli

Comment: @Daan /usr/local/php/bin/php doesn't work

Comment: @OliverBS Yeah, but there's a difference between php55-*php*-cli and php5-cli.

Comment: when you do a yum search there is no option for php5-cli nothing comes up

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Hey all and future me (I will of forgotten this next year),

To fix this issue I did two things.

1. `yum install php55`
2. `source /opt/remi/php55/enable`

to test running `php -v now works`

**update**

if you are using puppet you cannot run the command `source` so I found another solution

When you run the command `ls -la`  you can see that php will run but if you do `php56 -v` so my second option would be to symlink php to `/opt/remi/php56/root/usr/bin/php`

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ ls -la /usr/bin/ | grep 'php'
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root        32 Jan 28 16:57 php56 -> /opt/remi/php56/root/usr/bin/php
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root        36 Jan 28 16:57 php56-cgi -> /opt/remi/php56/root/usr/bin/php-cgi
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root        33 Jan 28 16:57 php56-pear -> /opt/remi/php56/root/usr/bin/pear
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root        38 Jan 28 16:57 php56-phar -> /opt/remi/php56/root/usr/bin/phar.phar
```

Comment: For Centos 6 after installing `yum install php54` I ran `source /opt/rh/php54/enable` to get `php` to work command line

Comment: I had to use the 'symlink' approach. It has to be done from one of the folders listed in the PATH variable though - I ran the command from /usr/local/bin

Comment: This also worked on rh-php56, had same problem. Not sure what to expect after reboot, I might need to create the symlink at that point...

Comment: This only works for the current session. If you re-login to the server the issue occurs again.

Answer (score 4):

I ran this in a docker (after installing remi in centos7):

```
yum -y --enablerepo remi,remi-php55 install php.x86_64 php-pecl-apcu.x86_64 php-pecl-memcached.x86_64 php-pecl-xdebug.x86_64
```

php -v returns PHP 5.5.34 (cli)

php -m shows correct modules

php --ini indicates all ini files in /etc/php.d are correctly installed